# How to capture returned data from server in JS without using JS http request functions?

Tags: javascript, httpresponse

Just to clarify the question a bit more, I am not asking about http requests with AJAX, $.post, $.get, and etc., or anything related to asynchronous call. The question I am asking about is related to the following situation..

User types a URL in browser, which triggers a server side function that returns a JSON object.

I am aware that this can be done with AJAX and other forms of http requests, but how do you capture the very first return on page load in javascript?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: AFIK if any url written on browser returns JSON browser will render the response as JSON directly and display it. I dont think you could capture that in any JS since reponse contains only JSON. my 2 cents

Comment: You dont, because the response is json and not a webpage in which javascript can be run

Comment: Hmm yeah that make sense.. I'm sure if it's possible, or maybe I just don't understand the concept.